# Date with timezone not parseable by generated code from WSDL in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, wsdl

My C# client has generated service based on WSDL file with these fields:

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date", Order=6)]
    public System.DateTime SomeDate{
        get {
            return this.SomeDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.SomeDateField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SomeDate");
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool SomeDateSpecified {
        ...
    }
```

Service is sending value

```
<v12:SomeDate>1972-07-05+01:00</v12:SomeDate>
```

According to documentation https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp
The Xml DataType "date" format should accept the timezone, However I am receiving error:

Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation '...'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2047). ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExactMultiple(String s, String[] formats, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)

I am aware that I can implement IClientMessageInspector and remove the timezone so it can be parsed, but I would like to avoid this.
The WSDL was provided to me from customer as

```
<xs:element name="SomeDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>
              ...
          </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
```

Comment: Are you sure the time "1972-07-05+01:00" is correct?  Looks like you have a timezone but no hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: @jdweng Seems legit for XML : http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77041.html

Comment: @Fildor : That link is a timezone enumeration, and not a date.  The tag name is Date, not Timezone.